# How to get the previous selected date in a MonthCalendar in C#

Tags: c#, memory, monthcalendar

let's say I have selected the date 12/22/2012

then I go on and select 11/19/2009.

I then try to so some code in

`private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)`

How would I be able to retrieve the date 12/22/2012? Would I need to keep some variables to do this? or is there something I could do to retrieve it?

Comment: I dont think you can "get" it, you need to track it on your own as state changes.  sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and tweak this,Create a static class and a variable `previousDate` in it and put some initial value to it,

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    string previous = myStaticClass.previousDate;
    current = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
    myStaticClass.previousDate=current ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
private string previous { get; set; }
private string current { get; set; }
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    previous = current;
    current = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Billy.. look at that code you need to assign previous properly it's = string.Empty based on the code that you have written..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't think that will be a problem, it is only going to be string.Empty the first Time a Date is Selected, which could be a valid state.